# Compare two matrix and find the matched index in the corresponding column

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

So I have two arrays. For each element in column i in `array_1`, I want to find whether the same element exists in column i in `array_2`. If it exists, I want the corresponding position/index in column i in `array_2`. If it doesn't exist, return False.

Instead of using for loop, I am wondering if there is any vectorized function that would do this task efficiently?

Below are two sample arrays and my desired output.

```
array_1 = np.array([[1, 2], [2 , np.nan]])
array_2 = np.array([[2, np.nan], [1 , 3 ]])

My desired output:
np.array([[1, False], [0 , 0]])
```

Comment: why does it return False for the '2' in position [0, 1]?

Comment: because 2 does not appear in column 2 of array_2